# IDisposable : Memory leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, idisposable

I'm currently do a review of a C# app in which I see that :

```
public static bool ServiceExists(string servicename)
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
    foreach (ServiceController s in services)
    {
        if (s.ServiceName == servicename)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865330/will-ignoring-idisposable-cause-memory-leaks/6865401#6865401), Henk said that the non-use of `Dispose()` (or `using`) will not generate memory leaks, true or false?

Can I keep the previous code has it is or should I write someting like :

```
public static bool ServiceExists(string servicename)
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
    bool exists = false;

    foreach (ServiceController s in services)
    {
        using(s)
        {
            if (s.ServiceName == servicename)
            {
                exists = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return exists;
}
```

What are the risks to no using `Dispose()` (or `using`) in this case?

Comment: Wrong example. This method does not _own_ th services. It shouldn't Dispose() them. And the 2nd version only disposes _some_ of them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I edited the 2nd version including your remark. On what can I base me to know if yes or no I should call `Dispose()`?

Comment: Only when the GetServices() method clearly documents that the responsibility shifts to the caller. Your version could very well result in runtime errors.

Comment: The object that OWNS the ServiceControllers should be the one to initiate Dispose on them.  If GetServices() is creating new instances of ServiceControllers, then you should initiate Dispose in this method.  Otherwise, the Dispose method should be called by the object that 'owns' these ServiceControllers.

Comment: Looking at the output of ILDASM on System.ServiceProcess.dll, it looks like it is necessary to Dispose() ServiceControllers returned by GetServices(). In GetServices, they call the ServiceController's constructor, passing it native resources. It might be worth noting that the MSDN sample code does not call Dispose(); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2 , this seems like a mistake on Microsoft's part and I hope they will clarify or update their docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correctly written object shouldn't cause a memory leak if it's `Dispose` method isn't called.  These days a .Net object which controls unmanaged resources should be doing so via a [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) instance.  These will ensure the native memory is freed even if `Dispose` is not called.

However it's very possible for objects which aren't written correctly to produce memory leaks if `Dispose` isn't called.  I've seen many examples of such objects.

In general though if you are using an `IDisposable` instance which you own you should always call `Dispose`.  Even if the object is correctly written it's to your benefit that unmanaged resources get cleaned up earlier instead of later.

**EDIT**

As James pointed out in the comments there is one case where not calling `Dispose` could cause a memory leak.  Some objects use the `Dispose` callback to unhook from long lived events which if they stayed attached to would cause the object to reside in memory and constitute a leak.  Yet another reason to always call `Dispose`

Comment: What about the case of the event handler which is unhooked in Dispose?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what ServiceController.GetServices() is doing.  If it is creating new instances of ServiceControllers when it is called, then it could cause a memory leak depending on what it needs to do (the ServiceController) in its Dispose method.

That said, adding 'using' in this case wouldn't fix it anyway as if you DID need to call dispose (implicitly via 'using' in this case) on each instance, it WOULDN'T as it returns whenever it finds a ServiceController with a matching name.

Therefore, if your first iteration found a matching ServiceController, all the other ServiceControllers wouldn't get disposed of anyway.